# Catch response code with Python 2.6 unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

Using unittest to test some edge cases with an API. All of these cases return 400-series response codes using custom exception classes. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to catch these custom exceptions or to read the response codes in the unittest check itself.

What I have been receiving is an 'AppError' exception with a message mentioning it is a 400 response rather than a 200 or 300. I want to avoid parsing the exception message if I can. This also needs to work on Python 2.6+. How can I either catch the custom exceptions in my unittest check, or determine the response code causing the error without parsing the exception message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Turns out that with webtest (which I forgot to mention as being used), you can pass in a parameter `expect_errors=True` and save the return value of the request. You can then check against the response status with

```
self.assertEqual('400 Bad Request', response.status)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to catch the exception and assert that it is not a 400 response:

```
try:
    call_api_method()
except AppError as ae:
    self.assert(ae.errorcode < 400)
```

This requires the exception to carry the error code as an attribute; you perhaps need to inspect what attributes are available on the exception. By default `.args` will be there (it is a tuple), but it is good practice for such exceptions to have an error code attribute too.

Comment: Unfortunately the error didn't appear to have any useful attributes. I did manage to figure out how to do this though.

Comment: @paradox870: Sorry to hear that; if the exception does not offer anything more than a string message, you have no recourse but to parse that. Otherwise, I hope to have been of *some* help.

Comment: Yea - I just posted my result as another answer. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: @paradox870: Right, it'd have helped if you included the fact that you were using `webtest` indeed. :-P